# Vor etwas nur so strotzen/wimmeln

Tags: meaning

Schon einige Male bekam ich die Wendung *vor etwas nur so strotzen/wimmeln* zu hören. Dabei kann ich nicht raffen, was "nur so" bedeutet und wann man es benutzt. Daher würde ich mich sehr freuen, wenn es mir jemand erklärte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Nur so" ist ein Verstärker. Es drückt aus, dass der Sprecher darauf hinweisen will, dass die Tätigkeit, die er dann nennt, in sehr intensiver Form ausgeführt wird.

> Der Ameisenhaufen wimmelte nur so vor Ameisen.
>
> Als Peter erfuhr, dass er einen Sechser im Lotto hatte, lallte er nur so vor Glück.
>
> Und dann sind wir zum Gardasee gefahren, aber da hat es nur so geschüttet.
>
> Die Brötchen waren so beliebt, dass der Bäckerladen vor Kunden nur so summte.
>
> Der Chef war sauer und schlug die Türe zu, dass es nur so krachte.
>
> Das war mal wieder eine Forums-Frage, die vor Fehlern nur so strotzte.
>
> Das Halsband, das sie trägt, strotzt nur so vor Klunkern.
>
> Als Ernst und Erna sich endlich wiedersahen, begrüßten sie sich so stürmisch, dass die Matratze nur so quietschte.

(Man kann das "nur so" in allen diesen Beispielen auch weglassen. Die Sätze sind trotzdem korrekt.)

Doch Achtung: Die Verwendung von "nur so" als Verstärker ist auf familiäre Ausdrucksweise beschränkt. Genauso übrigens dein "raffen" (was du vermutlich weißt, du wolltest nur einen Scherz machen, und jetzt kringelst du dich nur so vor Lachen).

Comment: Sehr ausführlich, danke! Ansonsten bin in in Sachen Stil und Ausdrucksweise noch nicht sehr erfahren, deswegen benutze ich manchmal unangemessene Wörter. Aber schön, dass Sie mir das erklärt haben. Danke nochmals.

Comment: Ihr Stil und Ihre Ausdrucksweise sind hervorragend. Lediglich das Wort "raffen" fällt aus dem Rahmen. Es wird eigentlich nur von Schülern/Jugendlichen verwendet, und auch nur in mündlicher Kommunikation. Normalerweise würde man  "verstehen" sagen (oder schreiben).

Comment: Ja, das Wort habe ich erst vor einigen Tagen gelernt und da hätte ich bedenken müssen, dass es von Jugendlichen benutzt wurde. Danke, dass Sie mich darauf hingewiesen haben :)