sich mit etwas bei jemandem werfen
I have read/heard the following sentence in the 2nd episode of the Lauchhammer TV series:

Angeblich hat er mit Einsen nur so um sich geworfen bei Ramona.

Context: the sentence is about Ramona's English teacher, which has been giving her As, even though she skips most classes.

What's the difference between "werfen" and "sich werfen"? Is the meaning of the latter really reflexive, i.e., is the guy throwing himself at Ramona ?
Is there a difference in meaning between "auf" and "bei" when used with "werfen"?


hint: um sich werfen

The sentence "He throws around a lot of A's," makes sense in English. The "bei Ramona" part throws me off though. How can it be both "um sich" and "bei Ramona"? DWDS has "mit+werfen" listed in the "mit Präposition" section, and two of the examples use "um sich", but there's nothing about "bei" listed. As an aside, the English name of the series is "Close to Home: Murder in the Coalfield". (I assume it has nothing to do with the 2005 US series "Close to Home".)

Maybe an English translation that works is "When he was Ramona's teacher, he threw around a lot of A's."

Bei Ramona is simply an adverbial; bei usually indicates a place, but here I'd translate in Ramona's case, following DWDS bei I.4.
The idiom is mit einer Sache um sich werfen. The preposition mit indicates what is being thrown; um sich indicates in all directions, all around. See DWDS werfen under 1.a. In Ramona's case, he threw around good grades is, I think, understandable English. The general meaning is using something a lot (mit Fremdwörtern um sich werfen), or wasting it (mit Geld um sich werfen).

Unrelated question: what does "so" mean in the sentence? Is it an intensifier?

See (in German) https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38073/vor-etwas-nur-so-strotzen-wimmeln.
